# Parallel parsing of files based on identifier in Python

Tags: python, parsing

I have some parallel files in the following format. The identifier is always the same, and the length of the numbers between the identifiers is the same. What changes between the files are the actual numbers. Finally, the numbers of parallel files can vary from 2 to 50

```
>Identifier1  
0
1
3
2
0
>Identifier2
0
4
1
>Identifier3
...
```

Since these files are big, (~3.5gb each) I don't want to load them into memory but to parse them in parallel based on the identifiers. So, for all the files pick up the first identifier and its corresponding values and call a function between all possible combinations. Then pick the second identifier and do the same ...

The first thing I tried in order to parse the files is the following:

```
import fileinput
from glob import glob
fnames = glob('tmp/test*')
for line in fileinput.input(fnames):
   print(line)
```

The problem with this is that it parses the file one after the other and not all of them at once.

The second thing (that is somewhow working) is to manually add the files using "with open". But this is not a good option since the number of files is not fixed. The following code is for combining two files.

```
from itertools import izip_longest
with open('tmp/test1', 'r') as a, open('tmp/test2', 'r') as b:
   flag = true
   for x, y in izip_longest(a,b):
           first = x.strip()
           second = y.strip()
           if(first[0]=='>' and second[0]=='>' and first==second):
                   if(flag is true):
                           flag = false
                           identifier = first
                           d1 = []
                           d2 = []
                   else:
                           print(cor(list(d1),list(d2)))
                           identifier = first
                           d1 = []
                           d2 = []
           else:
                   d1.append(first)
                   d2.append(second)
```

How can this be improved in order to work for multiple files?

## Update:

I found the following iterator online:

```
def isheader(line):
    return line[0] == '>'

def aspairs(file):
        for header,group in itertools.groupby(f, isheader):
                if header:
                        line = group.next()
                        ensembl_id = line[1:].split()[0]
                else:
                        sequence = ''.join(line.strip() for line in group)
                        yield ensembl_id, sequence
```

When I test it with one file it is working:

```
with open("tmp/test1") as f:
    for l in aspairs(f):
            print(l)
```

What I don't understand is how to combine it with the solution suggested by Tom.

Comment: You can make a list of all the files on the same folder and iterate on them (comparing two files at a time). This wouldn't be very efficient but is simple to code. A better solution would be to use multiple threads - each thread would read a line from a different file and one thread will compare all the Identifiers - this would be more complicated to implement and it might not be worth it if you are only scanning these files once - or if you don't require a high performing script.

Comment: If these are big files (you say they are), then attempting to "read them in parallel" from the disk is likely to not work.  The disk head is a point of serial contention, and can only "efficiently" read one file at time.  Your only hope in this case is that the computation you do for each identifier is very expensive, so that most of the time is spent computing, allowing the OS to fetch next file fragments concurrently with computation(s) on the current one.

Comment: This is interesting. Well what I calculate is the correlation coefficient between the lists. numpy.corrcoef(list1, list2). I don't know if this is "expensive" enough. Moreover, because the files are big i use the  izip_longest. I will give it a shot and I will let you know.

Comment: The file format superficially looks like FASTA, but you have numbers instead of sequences.  The file size also sounds like you are dealing with FASTA.  If so, you might want to add the [tag:fasta] tag to specifically reach Pytion bioinformatics programmers; the [tag:python] tag is very busy, so few people review all posts.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you can implement the izip method for multiple file names:

```
files = #create a list of filenames
open_files = [open(i, "r") for i in files]
for rows in izip(*open_files):
# rows is now a tuple containing one row from each file
# now you can compare each row with its identifiers
#Don't forget to close the files!
for file in open_files:
    file.close()
```

**UPDATE:**
Ok, I read your other comments and I think I understand what you are trying to do, so here is my revised code. The main point here is that I will create a list of lists, called numbers_list that takes (for each identifier) a number from each file and puts that number in the list corresponding with the file "index" - the first number (first line) from the first file will go into the first cell in the first list, the first number from the second file will go into the first cell in the second list, etc.. (if this is not clear please inform me).

```
import itertools

#create a list of filenames
files = ['file1', 'file2', 'etc...']
open_files = [open(i, "r") for i in files]

flag = TRUE
for rows in izip(*open_files):
    #rows is now a tuple containing one row from each file
    #use map to create list of string-similar to your x.strip()...
    row = map(str.strip, rows)
    if (reduce(lambda x, y: x if (x[0] == '>' and x==y) else false, row)):
        #not sure if this is what you need
        identifier = row[0]
        #numers_list would be a list of empty lists similar to d1 = [] d2 = [] but for n-lists: [[],[],...] one for each file
        numbers_list = [[] for x in row]
        if(flag): #not sure why you need this
            flag = FALSE
        else:
            print(cor(numbers_list))
    else:
    #This code will append each number from each file to the numbers_list: 
    #[[first_file_first_num,first_file_second_num,...],[second_file,first_num,second_file_second_num,...],...]
    for index, lst in enumerate(numbers_list[:]):
        lst.append(row[index])


#Don't forget to close the files!
for file in open_files:
    file.close()
```

Comment: I updated the question as it is not so clear to me how to actually use the above lines.

Comment: There is no point using the iterator method you described above since izip already creates an iterator object - which will not load the entire files to memory, but will only read one line at a time from each one of the files.

If you will explain in more detail what kind of comparison or function you want to use on all the lines I will be able to assist you further.
1. Do you want to compare line by line (take one number from each file and compare it with all the other numbers?)
2. Or, do you want to compare complete files (all the numbers from one file with all the numbers from another file)?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a way to solve this without sacrificing either running time or disk space.  A simple way to solve this somewhat more efficiently at the expense of some disk is to create an index.

So, for example, you could implement a two pass algorightm which creates an index on the first pass through the files.  Read all the files into memory, but don't keep the actual data in memory, just the offset of each identifier. Then create something like

```
Identifier1|file1:0:253|file2:1234:1279|file7:151617:151702
Identifier2|file1:254:307|file3:2345:2399|file6:65537:65613
Identifier3|file2:0:125|file6:120:199
:
```

Then on the second pass, read in one identifier at a time, `open()` each file, `seek()` to the specified offset, `read()` the specified range of bytes, and parse them.  When you have all the information for this identifier, you can write out the record for it, and move on to the next iteration, and the next input line from the index file.

The size of the index file could become a problem, but it sounds like it will be somewhat smaller than any of your individual input files; repeatedly `open()`ing and `seek()`ing the input files is obviously also going to be slower than just reading them through.  On the other hand, if you have trouble keeping all the data in memory, this shows you how to work around that.  Also, this scales to even really large inputs -- but then you will perhaps have to move to even more passes (only extract a subset of the identifiers to the index on each top-level pass, and repeat until you have covered them all).

Of course, this is just a brute alternative to putting the data in a database, and leverage its functionality to perform the merge.